# Access Kubernetes API using REST APIs

Tags: rest, api, authentication, kubernetes

I'm trying to access Kubernetes APIs from NodeJS. Running in environment where no kubectl or gcloud command line tools are available. Using https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript client side SDK. The question is how to authenticate and access the remote cluster. I need this for K8s running in GCP.

In other words trying to do what "gcloud container clusters get-credentials" does, but without "gcloud" cli.

Comment: "Running in an environment ..." that is _inside_ the cluster, or do you mean from your workstation (or something)?

Comment: Running outside the cluster, on. A workstation. Think it as a custom orchestrator that runs on top of kubernetes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can invoke Kubernetes API from `NodeJS` using this [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client) promoted by [GoDaddy](https://github.com/godaddy). `Kubernetes-client` for `NodeJS` simplifies a way how to adjust an interface to Kubernetes API.

Below example demonstrates a way how to use a small snippet to extract all the `Deployments` in the default Kubernetes `Namespace`:

```
const Client = require('kubernetes-client').Client;
const config = require('kubernetes-client').config;

const client = new Client({ config: config.fromKubeconfig(), version: '1.9' });
const deployments = await client.api.v1.namespaces('default').deployments.get();
```

[Here](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/tree/master/examples) you can find more snippets for using `kubernetes-client`.

Comment: The question is regarding authentication specifically. How can i pass a key created in gcp service account to the API to consume?

Comment: Take a look at official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Kubernetes Master API from outside, you need to authorize in one of the ways described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).

In particular, if you want to use username/password and you use GKE (k8 on GCP), then you can do it in the following steps:

1. Click on your cluster name and "Show credentials", there you can find Username and Password.
2. Use header: "Authorization: Basic BASE64ENCODED(USER:PASSWORD)" for your REST calls.

Comment: Is there a better way to that, one that doesn't require use of Admin user/password? Ideally I'd like to create a service account in gcp, and somehow pass its key to GKE APIs.